# bash- unzip compressed files in multiple directories at once

Tags: bash

I have a directory with many directories inside, each have multiple bz2 files inside. How can I unzip all of them in bash using bzip2 in their own directories at once?

Comment: Use `find` (see `man find`, and check the `-exec` option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
find ./ -iname "*.bz2" -exec bzip2 -d {} \;
```